# Why setting the preferred size to Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY or Double.MAX_VALUE does not work in JavaFX while 10000 does?

Tags: java, javafx

For some weird reason, if I try to set the height of a `HBox` with

```
setPrefHeight(10000)
```

it works wonders (it attempts to fill as much space as physically possible), while attempting any of the following (more obvious) options makes the layout go crazy:

```
setPrefHeight(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
setPrefHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

I've also tried to play around with the `setMaxHeight()` but it didn't seem to be much of a help (the results ended up being the very same). This is not a `HBox` specific behavior, as I've seen it happening with other kinds of controls too.

What's happening here?

Comment: Can you post an MCVE that demos the problem? Also, could you post the version of Java/JavaFX you are using?

Comment: I'll get you a MCVE. I'm running the JavaFX that comes with JDK10. I can get you more details when I get home.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the expected detail of an answer for this question, the reason may be simple:

It will exceed all limits, and not allow sensible computations any more.

When a class is responsible for the layout, and should lay out two components in two columns, then it might just do something **roughly** like that:

```
void layout() {
    double widthA = componentA.getPrefWidth();
    double widthB = componentB.getPrefWidth();
    double widthRequired = widthA + widthB;
    double widthAvailable = ...;
    double scaling = widthAvailable / widthRequired;
    componentA.setWidth(scaling * widthA);
    componentB.setWidth(scaling * widthB);
}
```

<sup>(That's some "pseudocode", of course. Reality is far more complicated)</sup>

Obviously, all these computations will run mad when encountering the values that you suggested. Adding anything to `Double.MAX_VALUE` will cause it go to `POSITIVE_INFINITY`:

```
double w0 = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double w1 = 1000;
System.out.println(w0 + w1); // Prints Infinity
```

And infinity is "viral". It will spoil all further computations:

```
double i0 = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
double i1 = 1000;
System.out.println(i0 - i1); // Prints Infinity
```

At some points inside JavaFX, there are "magic values". For example, preferred sizes of `null` or `-1.0` will cause the preferred size to be *computed* on the fly. They *could* also have decided to assign a special meaning to `MAX_VALUE` or `POSITIVE_INFINITY`, or to make all the layout computations agnostic of these special values ... somehow. But considering how complex layout computations may become, this would probably just have been a nuisance for the implementation, if it could be implemented reasonably at all...